# If $\sqrt{k-9}$ and $\sqrt{k+36}$ are both integers, the number of possible values of $k$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\sqrt{k-9}$ and $\sqrt{k+36}$ are both integers, the number of possible values of $k$ is: A) $1$; B) $2$; C) $3$; D) more than $3$.

I started to try different values of $k$ in the first root ($13, 18, 25, 34$) and see if $\sqrt{k+36}$ is an integer. So far I found $k=13$ is a solution. Are there any other solutions? Also, I don't think I am doing it in the fastest way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have $k-9=p^2, k+36=q^2$.  Then $q^2-p^2=(q+p)(q-p)=45$, so factor $45$ into two factors and check each possibility.  There are not many.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Let's first solve $a^2-b^2=45$ with $a:=\sqrt{k+36},\,b:=\sqrt{k-9}$ both integers $\ge0$. Since $(a-b)(a+b)=3^2\times 5$ must be a factorisation into two odd positive factors with $a-b\le a+b$, either $$a-b=1,\,a+b=45\implies a=23,\,b=22\implies k=b^2+9=493,$$ or $$a-b=3,\,a+b=15\implies b=6\implies k=45,$$ or $$a-b=5,\,a+b=9\implies b=2\implies k=13.$$So the answer is C).

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!